# Using a POST request to populate parameters for a CloudObject

Tags: wolfram-cloud, python

I am using *python* (ver. 2.7) in conjunction with *Wolfram Language* to create and build strings in a query language syntax. I have a successfully deployed an `APIFunction` that builds a query once parameters are specified and it is resent. I would like to populate these parameters with a *python* script that takes variable spoken input, then populates the `request`, and is then posted to the *Wolfram* API which is then resent. Here is what this looks like:

```
import requests

def wolfram_cloud():
    # query will be populated via spoken utterances; for now it's hard-coded for testing purposes
    query = ['VESSEL', 'EVENT', 'TRIGGERED', 'v', 'e']
    intent = dict(zip(['string1', 'string2', 'RelString', 'index1', 'index2'], query))
    url = "https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/0fc91bfb-ef6e-489b-ad07-8e6c25da21bb"
    requests.post(url, data=intent)
    return r.text
```

Will `requests.post` work in this case? There is some [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/embeddingformat/Python.html) on something similar to this (directly taking the `APIFunction` and instead of using `CloudDeploy[]`, deploying it via *python*) , but they are using a method different from `requests` which I'm not familiar with (I am fairly new to *python* and `urllib` has been largely replaced with `requests`; either way, it doesn't seem to populate the API request with a value for `x` anyway). If not (which has been the case so far, since I get nothing upon execution of this script), then why not; the *Wolfram Cloud* is still a bit of a mystery to me on how it works.

I know I can use the URL to the `CloudObject` when parameters are filled in and is sent for a`requests.get`, but that would mean that for every different utterance it would require a different `CloudObject`. I want the flexibility of being able to have many utterances that match the pattern in the `CloudObject` so I can have just the one URL, which is why I'm wondering if `requests.post` can fill in the parameters automatically, then resend the API request. I am basically hoping it can act like `URLExecute` would:

```
URLExecute[
"http://path-to-cloud-object", 
{"string1" -> "VESSEL", "string2" -> "EVENT" ...}, 
"Method" -> "POST"
]
```

Comment: I question whether this is the right place for this question, rather than stackoverflow.

Comment: @Feyre I thought about this before posting as well, but I figured that there are more folks here that have exposure to _Wolfram Cloud_ than in stackoverflow. However if others prefer moving the question over there, than I'd be happy to do so

Comment: Technically this SE is about Mathematica, and this question isn't. Stackoverflow also gets a lot more visitors, which you'll want considering the esoteric nature of the question. No one has requested a move, but if I were you I'd hedge my bets and ask on both.

Comment: The question you need to investigate on stackoverflow is how to get _python_ to include your parameters in the URL. If that doesn't solve you problem then edit the above question to show the APIFunction and _python_ code, and the Mathamatica end of the problem can be addressed here. On the other hand if the _python_ you get on stackoverflow just works, then I'm sure that others here would be interested in your answer to your own question.

Comment: My previous comment assumes that the `URLExecute` code posted in your question is actually working. If it's not, then my suggested stack overflow question may not be helpful.

Comment: You'll find another example of a _python_ `APIFunction` call in Jofre Espigule's answer to Wolfram Community post: [HackUPC: BarcelonaTech's Hackathon](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/802884).